Segmentation Fault during Balancing of violated AVL tree
I try to implement a program that illustrates the basic operation of an AVL tree. Previously I made that code as a Binary Search Tree and extended its operation to act as AVL. The issue comes every time the tree has to balance no matter what rotation. In all cases (LL LR RR RL) I get a segmentation fault. I can't find what I am doing wrong.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


//define the node for the BST
typedef struct node
{
    struct node * left;
    int data;
    struct node * right;
    int height;
}node;

typedef node * BST;

//function definitions 
void BST_INSERT(BST *tree,int data);
void BST_DESTROY(BST *tree);
BST NODE_CREATE(int data);
//AVL OPERATIONS
BST ROTATE_L(BST C);
BST ROTATE_R(BST C);
BST ROTATE_LR(BST C);
BST ROTATE_RL(BST C);
int max(int a,int b);
int height(BST C);



//main function
int main(void)
{
    BST t = NULL;
//case with seg fault 
   BST_INSERT(&t,10);
    BST_INSERT(&t,15);
    BST_INSERT(&t,20);
    BST_INSERT(&t,25);
//another case with seg fault 
    BST_INSERT(&t,0);
    BST_INSERT(&t,-5);
    BST_INSERT(&t,-10);
    BST_INSERT(&t,-15);
//non seg fault case 
 /* BST_INSERT(&t,10);
    BST_INSERT(&t,5);
    BST_INSERT(&t,15);
    BST_INSERT(&t,3);
    BST_INSERT(&t,6);
    BST_INSERT(&t,14);
    BST_INSERT(&t,16);

*/


    return 0;
}








//helper to create a new node before intgrating it to the tree
//its not nessecaty but is used in order to create some abstraction
//to the main function
BST NODE_CREATE(int data)
{
        BST new = (BST)malloc(sizeof(node));
        if(!new)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"error allocating memory\n");
            return NULL;
        }
        new->data = data;
        new->right = NULL;

        new->left = NULL;
        return new;
}
//insert a node in the BST
//recursively find the proper position for the element to be inserted 
//left wise for the smallest elementsprintf("___UNDER CONSTRUCTION___");
//right wise for the highest elements return 0;
//take as base case null
//if bigger than current element move to the right child 
//if equal or smaller than the current parent move to the left child 
//if the node is null place the element there 
//works also for uninitialized tree
void BST_INSERT(BST *tree,int data)
{
    //base case 
    if(*tree == NULL)
    {
        *tree = NODE_CREATE(data);
        return;
    }
    else if(data <= (*tree)->data)
    {
        BST_INSERT(&(*tree)->left,data);
    }
    else
    {
        BST_INSERT(&(*tree)->right,data);
    }

    // Update the height of the current node
    (*tree)->height = max(height((*tree)->left), height((*tree)->right)) + 1;

    // Check balance factor and perform rotations if necessary
    int balance = height((*tree)->left) - height((*tree)->right);

    // Left-Left Case
    if (balance > 1 && data <= (*tree)->left->data) {
        *tree = ROTATE_R(*tree);
    }
    // Left-Right Case
    else if (balance > 1 && data > (*tree)->left->data) {
        *tree = ROTATE_LR(*tree);
    }
    // Right-Right Case
    else if (balance < -1 && data > (*tree)->right->data) {
        *tree = ROTATE_L(*tree);
    }
    // Right-Left Case
    else if (balance < -1 && data <= (*tree)->right->data) {
        *tree = ROTATE_RL(*tree);
    }
}

//recursive aproach to destroy the binary search tree
//traverse to the lowest nodes from left to right
//if we reach null node then we destroy the node
//following the order left-right-parent
void BST_DESTROY(BST *tree)
{
    //base case NULL node 
    if(*tree == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    BST_DESTROY(&(*tree)->left);
    BST_DESTROY(&(*tree)->right);
    printf("deleting : %i ",(*tree)->data);
    free(*tree);

}

//find the height of the nodes and the maximum of them

int max(int a,int b)
{
    //return the highest height
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}
int height(BST C)
{
    //null node
    if(C == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return C->height;
}


//perform LEFT rotation
BST ROTATE_L(BST C)
{
    BST L = C->left;
    C->left = L->right;
    L->right = C;
    C->height = max(height(C->left),height(C->right))+1;
    L->height = max(height(L->left),height(L->right))+1;
    return L;
}

//perform right rotation
BST ROTATE_R(BST C)
{
    BST R = C->right;
    C->right = R->left;
    R->left = C;
    C->height = max(height(C->left),height(C->right))+1;
    R->height = max(height(R->left),height(R->right))+1;
    return R;
}
//perform rl rotation
BST ROTATE_RL(BST C)
{
    C->right = ROTATE_R(C->right);
    return ROTATE_L(C);
}
//perform lr rotation
BST ROTATE_LR(BST C)
{
    C->left = ROTATE_L(C->left);
    return ROTATE_R(C);
}





I didn't send the whole code because as I said I already implemented the code for a BST tree so I'm pretty sure it's correct. My considerations are on the rotation functions.
The insertions I tried were: 1,2,3,4 4,3,2,1 10,5,20,25,0 and I also tried insertions where all the elements don't violate the rules of the AVL. To be more accurate the insertions: 10,5,15,4,6,14,16,20 didn't caused a segmentation fault because they didn't break the rule.
You will see in my code a function called BST_DESTROY. This is to destroy the tree before the program ends. Currently in my program above I don't use it but it's fully functional.

What other information about the problem did your debugger provide?

You are not expected to show your whole code but a [mre], i.e. your code with everything removed/simplified that is not absolutely necessary for reproducing the problem. Run a debug version of your code with valgrind or use sanitizer options of your compiler. See e.g. https://airbus-seclab.github.io/c-compiler-security/

Shouldn't you initialize the height in NODE_CREATE?

This is a small program that fails without a great deal of computation. The proper approach to debugging it is to step through it in a debugger. You would watch each step execute and see what is going wrong in the step where the program fails. As you gain experience with the debugger, you will learn techniques for running the program up to an interesting point before failure without individually stepping through it entirely. Learning to use a debugger in this way is essential to becoming a good programmer, and understanding your program in detail is also essential…

… You should do these steps before posting to Stack Overflow. It is important that you understand the parts of your program and how they interact with each other. You cannot treat the program as mysterious or whole code that cannot be analyzed step by step and debugged by you. Understanding programs on the small scale and the large scale and knowing how to debug them is crucial, and you should develop skills for those by working with the program yourself, not asking Stack Overflow to diagnose the bug for you. Even if it seems difficult or tiresome, it is the better path to success.

Check your rotation logic. In BALANCE_L, you are setting
BST L = C->left;

and using L without checking that it is non-NULL:
L->right = C;


The original ROTATE_L function is actually rotating right, and the ROTATE_R function is actually rotating left. Swapping the names (and header comments) of the two functions seems to fix one of the problems.
An additional problem pointed out in a comment by @EmilioSilva is that the NODE_CREATE function is not initializing the height member. It needs to initialize the height member to 0 since it is being created at the bottom of the tree. Leaving it uninitialized could result in rotations being applied incorrectly, leading to further segmentation violations.

So after running it through a debugger the main issue with segmentation faults was in the height function and more specifically here
(*T)->height = max(height((*T)->left), height((*T)->right)) + 1;
Below is the definition of the function
int height(BST T)
{
    if(T == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return T->height;
}

The reason is because height function checks for NULL node but in my case there is the possibility to try to access the left or right child of a NULL node which will lead in segmentation fault .so to prevent the segmentation fault we have to add checks (if the main node is NULL).
    if (*T != NULL) 
    {
        (*T)->height = max(height((*T)->left), height((*T)->right)) + 1;
    }

the next issue is the rotation logic that as mentioned in the comments its the opposite .to fix this change ROTATE_R with ROTATE_L definitions
PS.Forgive me if my post is not 100% correctly documented but its my first post and i still learning .
